# MongoDb toArray

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongodb and in the following code I am using mongodb find().toArray(), but it is giving me the error "**Cannot read property 'toArray' of undefined**"

```
req.activedb.collection('items').find().toArray(function (err, data) {
    //...some code
})
```

whereas when I am using findOne(), then it is working properly.

```
req.activedb.collection('items').findOne(function (err, records) {
     console.log(err, records);        //Getting a single record here
})
```

**req.activedb is my current db instance**

Can you please tell me, what is missing here ?

Comment: Is the collection the same for both of those samples?

Comment: Ohh yes, sorry I forgot to update in the second example.

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved this issue.
Actually I was using **mongoose** to connect with my db, so it does not support find(). So now I am connecting to the db using **new Db()** method and it is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have run belows command its work for me.
     **posts** is nothing but **collection**.

```
db.posts.find().toArray();
```

You might be, you are making mistake in syntax .

Comment: No, the syntax was correct. Problem was the way I was using to connect to the db.